C connection to mysql gcc linker error in windows
I am using c in Windows. I need to use mysql.
I am having a really hard time trying to compile c code with mysql in it on Windows 11 os.
I had it easy in linux where I just needed to run either of the following 2 commands:
gcc -g3 -Wall main.c $(mysql_config --libs) -o main.exe $(mysql_config --cflags)

or even better:
gcc main.c -o main.exe -l mysqlclient

I have searched the whole internet. None was helpful. I tried all the gcc compiler commands and nothing worked.
Now, I need someone to help me with the command for gcc compiling c code with mysql on WINDOWS.
What is the windows equivalent of these 2 commands?
gcc -g3 -Wall main.c $(mysql_config --libs) -o main.exe $(mysql_config --cflags)

gcc main.c -o main.exe -l mysqlclient

Some c experienced programmers please help me. I really need to use Windows with c mysql integration as my clients all use Windows.
I tried the following but with the error message as per the output:
PS C:\Users\Ahmed Husein\Desktop\code\c_mysql_experiment> gcc -g3 -Wall main.o -o main.exe -L C:/'Program Files'/MySQL/'MySQL Server 8.0'/lib -lmysqlclient
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/mysqlclient.lib(libssl-3-x64.dll): Recognis
ed but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Ahmed Husein\Desktop\code\c_mysql_experiment/main.c:40: undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
C:\Users\Ahmed Husein\Desktop\code\c_mysql_experiment/main.c:41: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32'
C:\Users\Ahmed Husein\Desktop\code\c_mysql_experiment/main.c:42: undefined reference to `mysql_errno@4'
C:\Users\Ahmed Husein\Desktop\code\c_mysql_experiment/main.c:42: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
C:\Users\Ahmed Husein\Desktop\code\c_mysql_experiment/main.c:43: undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'
C:\Users\Ahmed Husein\Desktop\code\c_mysql_experiment/main.c:47: undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'
C:\Users\Ahmed Husein\Desktop\code\c_mysql_experiment/main.c:48: undefined reference to `mysql_server_end@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\Ahmed Husein\Desktop\code\c_mysql_experiment>


If you get some linker error, it would be best to show the exact and complete message in your question. You can edit the question to include it. I never tried that on Windows, but I don't think, $(...) is available on any Windows shell. Is mysql_config available as command in Windows shell? What is the result if you call these 2 commands manually? If the command is available, you can add the output into the command line instead of $(...)

the full error message, i have edited my original post...

okay i am sorry, have removed it...pls refer to what i tried and the error message as updated in my original post...

I am no mingw expert, but this looks wrong: .../mingw32/... together with .../mysqlclient.lib(libssl-3-x64.dll). You seem to mix 32 bit and 64 bit code. You either need to use 64 bit MinGw or find a 32bit version of your libraries

thanks! i will try to upgrade my linker to 64 bit and try again..

hi gerhardh, it worked after i deleted off my old mingw32 and installed mysys2 64-bit compiler and did the following:

a)
installed the mysql client for c/c++

b)
you need to add the following 2 paths for your linker for it to link both the mysql libraries ie libmysql.lib, for mysql server and mysql connector:
C:/'Program Files'/MySQL/'MySQL Connector C 6.1'/lib/opt (you need to add a further /opt, not sure why)
C:/'Program Files'/MySQL/'MySQL Server 8.0'/lib
then you need to link the libmysql.lib file using -l libmysql......
the full command:
g++ -Wall -g3 main.cpp -o main.exe -L C:/'Program Files'/MySQL/'MySQL Connector C 6.1'/lib/opt -L C:/'Program Files'/MySQL/'MySQL Server 8.0'/lib -l libmysql

thank you so much for the help and kind advice

by the way, how to you press enter in this comment session? i need to enter some space as all my comments above is cramped and untidy

Comments are not suitable for showing lengthy information. They cannot be formatted properly and might get removed. Therefore it is best to add relevant information to the question.

If you need MySQL connectivity I would recommend switching to MariaDB Client Library for C, which is still compatible with MySQL.
You can get the latest source code from https://mirror.mariadb.org/connector-c-current/

thank you! mariadb idea is great...for now, i have already found the answer to this question...and I am delighted with that...thanks for all the help
